# Why is my Siri getting activated in between conversation

Tags: iphone, siri

Recently Siri on my iPhone 7 latest iOS is getting activated, if I am speaking loudly e.g calling someone from first floor. It usually get activated when I call my son or my wife. This is creepy and I have privacy concern.Why is it happening and What should I do

Comment: I added a bit more to the answer. What specifically creeps you out?

Comment: @bmike of course the fact it just activated all of sudden

Comment: Got it, I can assure you, sound vibrations are making it activate each and every time. They don’t have to be audible to you either, so if there’s a prankster around you could be getting played. More likely it’s false positive or possibly a failing device.

Answer (score 1):

Siri on Apple products is programmed into the local code and hardware. If that code thinks it hears the key phrase, it will activate. If the vibrations local to the microphone are close enough to what you trained when you said hey Siri, it triggers.

I would set up Hey Siri again one time and then consider deactivating it if you can’t eliminate the false positives.

The Hey Siri function is optional and easily disabled if you don’t like and/or trust and/or understand how it’s implemented on the device.

Tap into the Settings app for Siri & Search and toggle the **Listen for “Hey Siri”** function off.

[image: image of hey Siri listening feature from iOS]

Good call on not automating something you don’t want and thinking about privacy. Even if the initial “Hey Siri” happens at some point and is processed on the device, the next verbal commands the microphone (mis)interprets might not necessarily be so safe or stay on the device.